# Is it possible to get the name of the current function/variable in a makefile

Tags: makefile

Is there a builtin variable like `.VARIABLES` that is the equivalent of `__FUNCTION__` in C?

I.e. the following..

```
my_variable=$(1) and $(.VARIABLE)

$(info $$(call my_variable,1) is "$(call my_variable,1)")
```

.. would output `$(call my_variable,1) is "1 and my_variable"`

Comment: I'm curious, what's this for?

Comment: See [the GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Call-Function) for the details about `call`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current function is `$0` (aka `$(0)`). Current variable isn't a thing.